# How can I use ListView in SlidingUpPanel of umano?

Tags: android

I'm using Sliding Up Panel library of umano. What I want to do is use ListView in the panel, but the problem is when I try to slide ListView, it will become sliding the panel instead. Please show me how to fix that. Thank you ;)

[image]

Comment: So you want to disable parent touch event right?

Comment: I think so, I want to slide ListView inside the panel, and when I don't want to use ListView anymore, I can slide the panel down.

Answer (score 4):

If you have a `ScrollView` or a `ListView` inside of the panel, make sure to set `umanoScrollableView` attribute on the panel to supported nested scrolling.

**Like this**

```
mSlideUpLayout.setScrollableView(mListView);
```

Comment: Not only `ListView`, we can make other views also scrollable.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out!

First you should change your **sothree:umanoDragView** in xml with header id (in my case is Viewpager id)

```
 <com.itsmo.android.zdcmap.widget.SlidingUpPanelLayout
                xmlns:sothree="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                android:id="@+id/sliding_layout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:gravity="bottom"
                sothree:umanoDragView="@+id/title_bar"
                sothree:umanoPanelHeight="50dp"
                sothree:umanoShadowHeight="4dp" >
```

Then in your activity, add 2 line:

```
mSlidingLayout.setDragView(mNameLayout);
mSlidingLayout.setEnableDragViewTouchEvents(true);
```

***mSlindingLayout is SlidingUpPanelLayout***

***mNameLayout is my ListView***